# Why there is an additional gap when inserting an eps using pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, texlive-2017

After updating to `texlive 2017` on a PC running `Linux Mint`, I found a strange problem about `pdflatex`. There is always an addition gap on the left side of the figure when inserting an `eps` file using `includegraphics`. But there is no such gap if I insert the `-eps-converted-to.pdf` version of the same eps.

For example, the following code generates a pdf. Pay attention to the gap in the left figure and on the left side of "YYYYYY".

There is no such gap if I use `xelatex`.

How to remove this gap? Is this a bug in `texlive 2017`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./}{figure/}}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \fbox{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{XXX}}%
  \fbox{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{XXX-eps-converted-to}}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) does this happen with every eps you try? If not, cat we have access to the eps in question?

Comment: @daleif It happens with every eps. I have downgraded to texlive 2016, and the issue disappears.

Comment: Not confirmed. I created an EPS with a visible white border (to make it easier to tell if there is cropping. Both images and boxes are the same when added to your MWE. Please provide the log file for when you run you MWE through TL17 pdflatex

Comment: @daleif This is the [eps](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/x728ypclwrv2uf8/AAAalQAmr9fk5QHol_mWFdrYa?dl=0) in my example. Let me re-upgrade to TL17, and provide you more info.

Comment: @daleif This issue occurs again. Log is provided in the same link.

Comment: Still not confirmed. If I use your EPS, the padding inside the frames are the same. Exactly which TL17 are you using? Something from Mint or the upstream TUG one?

Comment: Given the placement in the log, I'm guessing from Mint/Debian. BTW: since both boxes use the same image, the result shoulf be the same.

Comment: Please add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass`, recompile and show us the log. This will list all file versions in the log

Comment: @daleif (1) It is `Linux Mint 18.1`. (2) TL is updated using this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive). (3) There is no such problem before updating (TL16). (4) `\listfiles` is added and recompiled.

Comment: Interesting, I seem to have some older versions of a few files. I'll run an update

Comment: Now it is confirmed. Latest up to date graphics has an issue, I'll pass it on to the maintainers

Comment: Who are all ready working on it. A solution will probably be in the mirrors within a few days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maintainers have found the problem and an updted version of `pdftex.def` should be on its way to CTAN. Expect it on a local mirror within a day or two.

It was a sporadic space in a list, and this space survived and to interpreted by latex giving the left figure the with of the image plus one space.